# creating sub views(table inside another table) using backbone JS

Tags: backbone.js

Trying to create a table inside a table with backbone but could not able to find out a way. Can anybody help me out with an example to achieve this?

My Collection:

```
this.collection = new Backbone.Collection([
            { first: 'John', last: 'Doe', desig: 'E1', location: 'C' },
            { first: 'Mary', last: 'Jane', desig: 'E3', location: 'C' },
            { first: 'Billy', last: 'Bob', desig: 'E2', location: 'C' },
            { first: 'Dexter', last: 'Morgan', desig: 'E1', location: 'P' },
            { first: 'Walter', last: 'White', desig: 'E2', location: 'P' },
            { first: 'Billy', last: 'Bobby', desig: 'E1', location: 'B' }
        ]);
```

Normal View: Achieved this using a table view. refer code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/)

```
first    last    desig    location
----------------------------------
Billy    Bobby    E1       B
Walter   White    E2       P
Dexter   Morgan   E1       P
Billy    Bob      E2       C
Marry    Jane     E3       C
John     Doe      E1       C
```

Want to group by location then want to render as new view like below

```
location    first    last    desig    
----------------------------------
C           Billy    Bob     E2
            Marry    Jane    E3
            John     Doe     E1
P           Walter   White   E2
            Dexter   Morgan  E1
B           Billy    Bobby   E1
```

Using underscore we can do grouping but after that, I am struggling to render that object in the above view

```
_.groupby(this.collection, "location");
```

is giving me an object which has the required result.

Comment: You just need a collection view that renders a collection view. The input to first collection will be the result of `_.groupby`, input of child collection view will be one specific group, and the input of it's item view will be a specific record.

Comment: I tried creating one more view and while creating row view of the first table I tried to create the sub view but did not work for me. Can you point to an example so that I can learn and implement?https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/2/

Comment: In the fiddle you only have 2 views. Please share your attempt with 3 views. All you need is another view that creates tables bodies

Comment: I have tried to create the view i needed and updated the fiddle only one problem is that the group values are starting from column one instead column 2                                                                                                              
    https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/3/    I need the grouped values inside the main table data column.

Comment: Changed the el and its started working fine. @T J please validate and let me know if you have a better approach. Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/6/

Comment: Updated fiddle with 2 different views using user input https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/10/

Comment: Semantically your `RowSubView` should be `<tbody>` insted of `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

Every row in the table should be represented in a Backbone.View.
The grouping you want is mostly a `rowspan` feature of standard HTML tables.

See the snippet:

```js
var collection = new Backbone.Collection([{
  first: 'John',
  last: 'Doe',
  desig: 'E1',
  location: 'Chennai'
}, {
  first: 'Mary',
  last: 'Jane',
  desig: 'E3',
  location: 'Chennai'
}, {
  first: 'Billy',
  last: 'Bob',
  desig: 'E2',
  location: 'Chennai'
}, {
  first: 'Dexter',
  last: 'Morgan',
  desig: 'E1',
  location: 'Pune'
}, {
  first: 'Walter',
  last: 'White',
  desig: 'E2',
  location: 'Pune'
}, {
  first: 'Billy',
  last: 'Bobby',
  desig: 'E1',
  location: 'Bangalore'
}]);

var GroupRowView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.groupBy = options.groupBy;
    this.index = options.index;
    this.total = options.total;
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    if (this.index == 0) {
      this.$el.append('<td rowspan="' + this.total + '">' + this.model.get(this.groupBy) + '</td>');
    }
    _.each(this.model.omit(this.groupBy), function(value, key) {
      this.$el.append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
});

var SimpleRowView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  render: function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    //this.$el.append('<td>' + this.model.get('location') + '</td>')
    _.each(this.model.values(), function(value) {
      this.$el.append('<td>' + value + '</td>');
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
})

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'table',
  render: function() {
    /*var self = this;
    self.$el.empty();
    self.collection.each(function(rowModel) {
      self.$el.append(_.template('<tr><td><%= location %></td><td><%= first %></td><td><%= last %></td><td><%= desig %></td></tr>')(rowModel.attributes))
    });*/
    var self = this;
    self.$el.empty();
    self.collection.each(function(model) {
      var row = new SimpleRowView({
        model: model
      });
      self.$el.append(row.render().el);
    });
    return this;
  },
  groupCollection: function() {
    var self = this;
    var groups = self.collection.groupBy('location');
    self.$el.empty();
    _.each(groups, function(group) {
      var length = group.length;
      _.each(group, function(model, i) {
        var row = new GroupRowView({
          model: model,
          groupBy: 'location',
          index: i,
          total: length
        });
        self.$el.append(row.render().el);
      })
    })
  }
});
var table = new TableView({
  collection: collection
});

$('#table-container').append(table.render().el);
$('#sortBtn').click(function(e) {
  table.groupCollection();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>


<p>What the table should be:</p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Desig</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">C</td>
      <td>Billy</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>E2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Marry</td>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>E3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>E1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">P</td>
      <td>Walter</td>
      <td>White</td>
      <td>E2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dexter</td>
      <td>Morgan</td>
      <td>E1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">B</td>
      <td>Billy</td>
      <td>Bobby</td>
      <td>E1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>What the resulting table is:</p>

<button id="sortBtn">Sort!</button>

<div id="table-container">

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `self` as `_.each` takes am optional third param which is the context of the callback: `_.each(list, callback, this)`

Comment: @EmileBergeron I knew that but I thought that it will be something easy to miss while explaining. Personally I like using `.bind(this)` since it draws attention to this Javascript "gottcha" and you don't use unnecessary variables. Heck, even es6 fat arrow function would be more elegant but I was confused: In 2017, using Backbone seems like sticking to the past and I shouldn't bother using or explaining any modern Javascript. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Do not misuse functions and instead favor good practices when writing answers. If you feel that the _context_ param is easily missed, you could add a comment pointing that out. ES6 in this question would be out of scope. I don't think Backbone is sticking to the past and I believe it works well with ES6 new features.

Comment: While an arrow function would work with the `_.each` callback, it doesn't work within `Backbone.View.extend` because arrow functions aren't meant to be used within a prototype, period. Nothing to do with Backbone.

Answer (score -2):

Updated fiddle with 2 different views using user input

jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/ddbf9ckv/10

Let me know anybody has a better approach to achieve this.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with user input or different view for device. your answer should answer the question, as if you are a different person who doesn't know about other requirements of your project. This is a Q&A site. If you feel like the Q & A won't be useful for others just delete the question instead of answering like this